# Add Showcase / Highlight Flutter

Tags: flutter, showcaseview

I have the flutter code to display the showcase or highlights using https://pub.dev/packages/showcaseview/example

I want to show a long description which is 3 lines, is this possible?
now when my description is long it will show 1 line

```
Showcase(
                              key: _one,
                              description: 'I WANT ADD LONG DESCRIPTION HERE,I WANT ADD LONG DESCRIPTION HERE, I WANT ADD LONG DESCRIPTION HERE,  ',
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.menu,
                                color: Colors.black45,
                              ),
                            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `\n` in your text. Something like:

```dart
'I WANT ADD LONG DESCRIPTION HERE,\nI WANT ADD LONG DESCRIPTION HERE,\nI WANT ADD LONG DESCRIPTION HERE,  ',
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: if I add \ n,
Can the box description be adjusted in size? because the width fills the screen, it should appear in the middle

Comment: @RohmatulLaily As per the source code of `showcaseview`, I'm seeing they align the text to `center` if the title is not `null`. The size is adjusted to fit the content as well